# NFC Background reading on iOS - universal link keeps opening in Safari

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nfc, ios-universal-links

I'm dealing with a strange issue where I've successfully set up Universal Link on iOS, and I can click on my domain from my phone and get taken straight to the app.

However, I want to set up NFC background reading, and have been following this tutorial:
https://medium.com/appcoda-tutorials/building-nfc-product-scanner-ios-app-with-corenfc-alfian-losari-5da0365bcde5

Per the tutorial, I've

1. encoded an NFC sticker with the URI https://example.com/sku
2. added the string "applinks:example.com" to my entitlements for associated domains
3. set up universal links and verified that clicking "https://example.com/sku" from, say, iMessage takes me to my app

However, when I read the NFC sticker, I consistently get a Website NFC Tag notification that takes me into Safari. Can anyone please help me debug why this might be the case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As is stack overflow tradition, I would like to record my idiocy here for posterity:

The subdomain also needs to be included in the applink: on closer inspection, I realized the NFC stickers were encoded with "www.example.com".

Comment: I have the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807840/ios-nfc-background-reading-not-catched-by-application. Can you explain in more detail what you did? I have double check the correct domain name but my App does not catch the URL. There is only the notification from Safari to open the URL.