# iOS NFC Background reading not catched by Application

Tags: ios, background, nfc, ios-universal-links

I try to implement NFC Background reading on iOS.

I setup my application:

1. added the string "applinks:www.example.com" to my entitlements for associated domains
2. add associated domains to Entity Settings in App profile

The problem is that after scanning the NFC Tag in background there is only shown a notification to open the URL within Safari browser. It is the same URL which I have added in "applinks:" setting.

In fact it is the same problem like in following link where the user solved the problem by adjusting the URL:

[NFC Background reading on iOS - universal link keeps opening in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58636140/nfc-background-reading-on-ios-universal-link-keeps-opening-in-safari)

Is there any possibility to debug this issue? How can I check if the 'url catching' is working?

Comment: No sure if it would help but try remove the app then reinstall it, if you made any changes to the universal link settings to apply this new settings.